# fill dropdown list by querystring

Tags: asp.net

I had drop down list and I want to fill it with data by specific condition 
i used this code but it was,t worked well

```
<cs>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.Title = "ThumbnailViewPage";

    if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {

            SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("GetProducFamilyTP2", Con);
            Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Category_Id", Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader DR = Com.ExecuteReader();
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                DDlProductFamily.DataTextField = DR["Name"].ToString();
                DDlProductFamily.DataValueField = DR["ProductCategory_Id"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }
    else if (Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"] != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
        {

            SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("GetProducFamilyTP3", Con);
            Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@ProductCategory_Id", Request.QueryString["ProductCategory_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader DR = Com.ExecuteReader();
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                DDlProductFamily.DataTextField = DR["Name"].ToString();
                DDlProductFamily.DataValueField = DR["ProductCategory_Id"].ToString();
            }
        }

    }
```

}

```
                                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                                        <ContentTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDlProductFamily" runat="server" 
                                                ondatabound="DDlProductFamily_DataBound" onload="DDlProductFamily_Load" 
                                                onselectedindexchanged="DDlProductFamily_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </ContentTemplate>
                                        <Triggers>
                                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DDlProductFamily" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                        </Triggers>
                                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you explain what the actual problem is?

Comment: I cannot fill drop down list with values from data base as code shown up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
DDlProductFamily.DataSource = DR;
DDlProductFamily.DataBind();
```

or

```
if (DR.Read()) {
   DDlProductFamily.DataSource = DR;
   DDlProductFamily.DataTextField = "Name";
   DDlProductFamily.DataValueField = "ProductCategory_Id";
   DDlProductFamily.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: ok I did this as 
if (DR.Read())
                {
                    DDlProductFamily.DataSource = DR;
                    DDlProductFamily.DataTextField = DR["Name"].ToString();
                    DDlProductFamily.DataValueField = DR["ProductCategory_Id"].ToString();

                    DDlProductFamily.DataBind();
                   
                }

But this error appear 

DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name '4Door'.