# fill dropdown list by querystring

Tags: asp.net

I Had Drop down list and I want to fill it with data from database through stored procedure 
and it had it,s value when specific query string I had two query string.

as

private void LoadWithCategory()
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["Category_Id"] != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection Con = Connection.GetConnection())
            {

```
            SqlCommand Com = new SqlCommand("GetProducFamilyTP", Con);
            Com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Com.Parameters.Add(Parameter.NewInt("@Category_Id", Request.QueryString["Category_Id"]));
            SqlDataReader DR = Com.ExecuteReader();


            if (DR.Read())
            {
                DDLProductFamily.DataSource = DR;
                DDLProductFamily.DataTextField = DR["Name"].ToString();
                DDLProductFamily.DataValueField = DR["ProductCategory_Id"].ToString();

                DDLProductFamily.DataBind();

            }
            DR.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

ALTER  Proc GetProducFamilyTP
(
@Category_Id Int 
)
AS
Select Distinct Categories.Category_Id ,ProductCategory.Name ,
ProductCategory.ProductCategory_Id
From Category_ProductCategory

Inner Join Categories
On 
Category_ProductCategory.Category_Id=Categories.Category_Id
Inner Join ProductCategory
On 
Category_ProductCategory.ProductCategory_Id=ProductCategory.ProductCategory_Id
Where 
Categories.Category_Id   =@Category_Id

but this error occurred

DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name '4Door'.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645639/fill-dropdown-list-by-querystring

Comment: but Error I cannot solved it and I mentioned it up

Comment: Check your procedure and your table - the error say it clear, can not find the '4Door'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in ddl list when I removed it it worked well it had value=0